# Error installing Webmin

Tags: unix, centos

Having some problems installing Virtualmin ( http://www.webmin.com/vinstall.html ). I'm fairly new to Unix terminals and all that, but proficient enough to have been able to install and configure a LAMP stack correctly so far on a MediaTemple (ve). :)

My problem is that I'm trying to install Virtualmin. I've `wget` the `install.sh` file into my home directory. I then run the command `./install.sh` to launch the installation process. The disclaimer and warnings appear, asks if I want to continue. I hit `Y` and then:

`/tmp directory is mounted noexec.  Installation cannot continue.`

A bit of googling suggests this is a problem in the /etc/fstab file. When I `sudo nano /etc/fstab` this is the output:

`none    /dev/pts       devpts  rw      0       0`

Would someone be able to advise either:

1) How to edit this fstab file to stop /tmp being noexec...? or
2) An easier/different way of installing Virtualmin? I wasn't too sure if there was a `yum` way of doing it or something.

Cheers!

Jack

Comment: Woops - posted to the wrong site, silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the RPM [here](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin-1.520-1.noarch.rpm), and install it with `rpm --aid webmin-1.520-1.noarch.rpm`. It probably will also give you the noexec error - you can fix it by typing `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` before installation, and `mount -o remount,noexec /tmp` after.

Copy-and-pasting the below into a root terminal should do all of the above:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/webadmin/webmin/1.520/webmin-1.520-1.noarch.rpm?r=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F196150%2Ferror-installing-webmin%2F196154&ts=1288356140&use_mirror=kent
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
rpm --aid webmin-1.520-1.noarch.rpm
mount -o remount,noexec /tmp
```

Comment: This doesn't look too promising: 'mount: permission denied' ... :( - thank you for your answer though! Any ideas?

Comment: You should be root before attempting the above, as I said. To become root, you can either type `su -` and enter the root password, if you know it, or `sudo -i` and enter your password, if sudo is installed and you have permission to use it.